# R: Is there a way to set the terminal interpreter to allow line wrapping instead of cutting off with a dollar sign ($)?

Tags: r

When using the R interpreter from the terminal/command line, a line of code longer than 75 characters gets cut off from view with a preceding `$` sign, as shown here. Both pictures are different views of the same line of code.

[image: the beginning of a command cut off with a dollar sign]
[image: the end of a command cut off with a dollar sign]

(I know the whole command is there and I can use the arrow keys/home/end to go through it.)

This makes the interpreter harder to use when pressing "up" to rerun previous lines of code with one or two small changes, since I have to scroll through the line to find the right spot. It'd be easier if I could just see the whole line. It's also a bit silly since my usable screen area is much wider than 75 characters. Is there a setting I can modify so that the lines will wrap, or at least allow them to be longer before getting cut off?

Comment: what are your `options()$width
[1] 80` and `options()$continue
[1] "+ "` (note the space after), that can be set `options(width = 85)`, `getOption('width")`. Bunch of things to read at `?options`,

Comment: My `options()$width` is set to 250, which works for printed text, but doesn't seem to affect entered commands.  `options()$continue` is `+ `, but that only seems to cover when I press enter to break a line of code. While that works fine for entering the code, it's not as helpful for repeating a line, since I have to hit the up arrow multiple times and then enter them again one-by-one. I didn't see anything else at `?options` that looked relevant, but it's possible I missed something.

Comment: And I could be off base.